# How to jump to a space containing a window for the active application?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, osx-spaces, alt-tab

I'm using 4 Spaces with the "When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application" option turned off. But that means it's sometimes a real hunt trying to find the right space for an app. Is there a shortcut key or something that will do this?

To spell it out, because this might be unclear:

1. I open an application X in space 1
2. Sometime later I'm in space 4, and want to go to application X
3. I alt-tab, now X is the active application - but I'm in space 4, and I can't see any windows.
4. I start trawling around the various spaces, trying to remember where X's windows are.
5. (Ideally instead I would push some key and jump straight somewhere useful)

I'm pretty new to OS X, so feel free to point out the bleeding obvious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the application's icon in the Dock the second time, it will behave as if *When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for that application* was checked.

You can also get a list of open windows in an app by secondary-clicking its Dock icon.

Edit:

Other suggestions include using Switching using Expose, my personal favorite. It's the closest thing to   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>   <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: @Lri: No, it's not option click.  I meant clicking the dock icon.  Click it once will activate the application.  If there are no windows for the application currently in the space it merely activates the pplication.  Clicking it again causes you to switch spaces.  The check box, which has one of the most suck explanations, merely turns off the behavior for the first click so, for example, you can open a new Browser window in your current space. I didn't read the last line and should of included more options.

Comment: Great - didn't know about repeat-clicking on the Dock icon. (Subsequent clicks cycle through spaces with windows)

I didn't quite catch the Ctrl+Alt+Tab reference - is that a Windows 7 thing? (I'm used to XP)

Comment: Oh yeah, it's a Vista/7 hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to use [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/). It's a customizable replacement for the application switcher that is window-based like alt-tab on Windows.

[image]